# Does RavenDb Spatial search uses SRID

Tags: ravendb, spatial

I'm researching RavenDb for my organization and one of the main research parameters is the spatial search. I tried to find if Raven enables Spatial search using SRID but couldn't find any info.
Does it consider the datum of the stored geometries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, RavenDB doesn't use SRID.
For spatial searches, it relies on Spatial4n, a port of Spatial4j: https://github.com/spatial4j/spatial4j